# Etymology of nouns "Rede" and "Gespräch" comparing to verbs "reden" and "sprechen"

Tags: etymology

I would like to know, why does the noun *Rede* means *speech* while the verb *reden* means *to talk* and, similarly, *Gespräch* means *conversation* while *sprechen* means *to speak*? Intuitively speaking, *Gespräch* should mean *speech* and *Rede*, *conversation*, due to their roots. Why are the meanings "switched"?

Comment: Asking for *logic* in a language can cause havoc. And you haven't even asked for *Gerede*, *Ansprache* and *Anrede*...

Comment: I know, it just made curious. Those you mentioned at least follow their roots, so *-rede* involves talking, and *-sprache*, speaking, while the ones I mentioned switched meanings entirely.

Comment: Other related words are *Sprache*, *Gerede* and *Sprech*.

Comment: Morphologically, you should compare these pairs instead: _Rede ∶ Sprache/Sprech(e), Gerede ∶ Gespräch/Gespreche, reden ∶ sprechen_. Note that one verb inflects strongly, the other doesn’t, e.g. _redete ∶ sprach_. Also, depending on context (e.g. _miteinander_ or _über_), both can be translated as either  _talk_ or _speak_ into English, so the question probably results from an false, anglocentric understanding.

Comment: This post http://www.experto.de/kommunikation/reden/das-wort-rede-und-seine-etymologie.html at least explains the etymology of Rede, which as many words has its origin in latin.

Answer (score 1):

Going to my trust etymology source may offer an explanation:

*sprechen* has

> noach. *ʙërëκ- 'bitten, beten' D
>
> ```
> japhet. *prëg- trans. 'auf jemand einreden: fragen, bitten'
>
>     *śprëg- intr. 'sich äußern'
>
>         alban.
>
>             shpreh 'ausdrücken, äußern'
>
>             shrehí 'Gewohnheit, Angewohnheit'
>
>             shpréhje 'Ausdruck, Äußerung, Redensart, Sprichwort, mathematische Formel'
>
>         cymr.
>         zu cymr. ff < sp siehe Spund
>
>             ffraeth 'redegewandt, spitzfindig, witzig, leichtfertig†'
>
>             ffrec, -g 'Geschwätz, Geplapper, Kauderwelsch, Quatsch'
>
>             † fregl 'Erzählung'
>
>         wgerm. sprekan > *sprekan 'sprechen'
>
>             aengl. sprecan > specan 'sprechen'
>
>                 engl. speak 'sprechen'
>
>             afries. spreka 'sprechen'
>
>             and. sprekan 'sprechen'
>
>             ahd. 7" sprehhan (8" spehhan) 'sprechen'
>
>                 nhd. sprechen 'reden'
> ```

And

> Proto-IE: *(s)pelǝ-
>
> Meaning: to appeal
>
> Old Greek: apẹ̄lǟ́ f. `ruhmredige Verheissung; Drohung'; apẹ̄léō`prahlend verheissen; drohnen'
>
> Baltic: *pel̂- (2) vb. tr., *pal-iā̃ f.
>
> Germanic: *spill-a- n., *spill-ō- vb.
>
> Latin: appellāre `ansprechen, anreden, nennen, mahnen, anklagen', compellāre`anreden, angehen, schelten, anklagen', interpellāre `durch Zwischenreden unterbrechen, Einspruch erheben'
>
> Russ. meaning: апеллировать

So, it's source is one of a "quieter" one on one form of conversation - essentially from talking to someone with an appealing tone to get something out of them.

*reden* on the other hand

> Proto-IE: *rAwǝ-
>
> Meaning: to shout, to roar
>
> Old Indian: rauti, ravīti, ruváti, ravati `to roar, bellow, howl'; ráva-, ravátha- m.`roar, yell'
>
> Old Greek: ōrǖ́omai̯, aor. ōrǖ́sasthai̯ `heulen, brüllen, wehklagen', adv. ōrǖdón`heulend', ōrǖthmó-s (~ -ü-) m. `Heuler, heulend'
>
> Slavic: *rjūtī, *revǭ; *rūjītī Baltic: *raû-n-ā̂ (1) f.
>
> Germanic: *rū-ja- vb., *riu-n-ia- vb., *riu-n-i- adj., *riu-n-ō- vb.,
>   *ru-m-ja- vb., *ru-m-ja- m.; *ráu-s-a- n., *rau-s-t=, *ráu-s-ōn- f.
>
> Latin: rūmor, -ōris m. `dumpfes Geräusch; Murmeln, Summen; Gerücht,
>   Volksstimmen, Beifall', ravus, -a`heiser', ravis, acc. -im
>   `Heiserkeit', raucus, -a`heiser, schrillend, dumpf, schnarrend',
>   rāvīre `heiser reden'
>
> Russ. meaning: кричать, реветь

Which means it's a loud utterance - as noted also as a form of applause - uttered more loudly and to more than one person.

So, summarised, *sprechen* has its source in one-on-one and *reden* in one-to-many speech.

Answer (score 0):

*Gespräch* is the result when many people *sprechen*. 
"Rede" is one person speaking (reden) on his own. "reden" can also refer to one person talking while others listen.